# Can Gnus nnimap split articles to other imap server?

Tags: gnus

At work we have a limited storage quota on the email server so I have set up Dovecot on my laptop as an email archive that I also access using IMAP.  Besides archiving I also store all email from mailing lists on the local server.

Recently I have been trying to rid myself of Thunderbird and use Emacs for all emailing and as part of that I have migrated my filter rules to `nnmail-split-fancy` rules.  However, so far I have not been able to get `nnmail` to successfully move email from my inbox (company IMAP) to my archive (local Dovecot IMAP), is this at all possible to do?

My configuration looks something like this:

```
(add-to-list
 'gnus-secondary-select-methods
 '(nnimap "me@company.com"
          ...))
(add-to-list
 'gnus-secondary-select-methods
 '(nnimap "me@company.com-archive"
          ...))

(setq
 nnimap-split-methods 'nnmail-split-fancy
 nnimap-split-download-body-default t
 nnmail-split-fancy
 '(|
   (: nnmail-split-fancy-with-parent)
   (list ".*linux-users.*"
         "me@company.com-archive:Mailing Lists.Linux Users")))
```

I also tried appending "nnimap+" to the destination and various other combinations but every time an email matches the rule Gnus will simply create a folder called `me@company.com-archive:Mailing Lists.Linux Users` on the company IMAP server and move the email there instead of going to my local server.

My complete Gnus configuration, except for machine local settings, is available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dholm/dotemacs/master/.emacs.d/lisp/apps/gnus.el).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnus splitting does not work across servers.

I would recommend instead to treat your company IMAP server as a mail source, as described in https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Mail-Source-Specifiers.html

You can still keep using it in your `gnus-secondary-select-methods` as far as I know.

Comment: If I treat it as a mail source will it pop my email from the IMAP server?  I really need to keep "current" email threads on the server as a backup and so that I can access it over the web in an emergency.

Comment: Look at the page I cited.  The `:predicate`, `:fetchflag`, and `:dontexpunge` options will help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it came up for me recently, and no, you cannot split across IMAP servers.

I didn't want to set the one server as just as a mail source, as then I would only be able to fetch from a single folder (i.e. INBOX), or else I'd have to set up multiple sources for multiple folders.

So what I did was write a function that, after finding mail on the second server, would *move* it to the other server. Not split, but move. It is perfectly possible to move mail between servers with gnus commands.

Here is an example, I hope it renders correctly.

```
(defun rjn-move-mail-between-groups ()
  "Move between mailboxes based probably on foreign servers"
  (interactive)
  ;; Simplest to add additional moves below this point.
  (rjn-do-mail-move "nnimap+aol:INBOX" "nnimap+imap.gmail.com:INBOX")
)

(defun rjn-do-mail-move (frombox tobox)
  "Move mail between mailboxes, even if between different IMAP 
   servers"
  (save-window-excursion
  (if (get-buffer "*Group*")
      (with-current-buffer "*Group*"
     (if (gnus-group-goto-group frombox t)
           (if (or (gnus-group-select-group) (gnus-topic-select-group))
           (progn
             (gnus-uu-mark-buffer)
             (gnus-summary-move-article nil tobox nil)
             (gnus-summary-catchup t t)
             (gnus-summary-exit)))))))
)
```

(add-hook 'gnus-after-getting-new-news-hook 'rjn-move-mail-between-groups)